# How to display image in message part in wp_mail function?

Tags: wordpress, email

I am trying to send mail when a post is published. For that I wrote code in my function.php file, the mail is correctly sending, but the featured image is not sent. I want to display the featured image attached to the post. Right now in mail the featured image is not displayed, but the link of fthe eatured image is displayed.

What can I do to achieve my task to display the featured image in the mail? I am attaching the code I have written in function.php file:

```
function mysendmail($post_id) {

$post = get_post($post_id);
$author = get_userdata($post->post_author);
$subject = "Post Published: ".$post->post_title."";

$message = "
      Hi ".$author->display_name.",

      Your post, \"".$post->post_title."\" has just been published.

      View post: ".get_permalink( $post_id )."

      Your Image: ".get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID )."

      Thanks"
      ;

   wp_mail($author->user_email, $subject, $message);
}
add_action('publish_post', 'mysendmail');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To attach file through wp_mail function, you need to use $attachments parameter in it. In which you need to give absolute file path of attachment.

```
function mysendmail($post_id) {

$post = get_post($post_id);
$author = get_userdata($post->post_author);
$subject = "Post Published: ".$post->post_title."";


$attachments = get_attached_file( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post_id ));
$headers[] = '';


$message = "
      Hi ".$author->display_name.",

      Your post, \"".$post->post_title."\" has just been published.

      View post: ".get_permalink( $post_id )."

      Thanks"
      ;

   wp_mail($author->user_email, $subject, $message, $headers, $attachments);
}
add_action('publish_post', 'mysendmail');
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the content type to `text/html` for the image to work. You can do that using the `wp_mail_content_type` [filter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/wp_mail_content_type) or by adding a header into your `wp_mail()` function. Here's an example of the latter.

```
function mysendmail($post_id) {

    $post = get_post($post_id);
    $author = get_userdata($post->post_author);
    $subject = "Post Published: ".$post->post_title."";
    $headers = array('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

    $message = "
          Hi ".$author->display_name.",

          Your post, \"".$post->post_title."\" has just been published.

          View post: ".get_permalink( $post_id )."

          Your Image: ".get_the_post_thumbnail( $post->ID )."

          Thanks"
          ;

    wp_mail($author->user_email, $subject, $message, $headers);
}
add_action('publish_post', 'mysendmail');
```

Comment: Just tried yore code for adding header into wp_mail() function,but in mail output,the "your image:" field is displaying blank.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one, just tested on a local install and it works well :) you need to change the content type for the mail as discussed, also im returning the actual URL of the image (large size).

```
function set_html_content_type() {
    return 'text/html';
}
function mysendmail($post_id) {
add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'set_html_content_type' );

$post = get_post($post_id);
$author = get_userdata($post->post_author);
$subject = "Post Published: ".$post->post_title."";

$image = get_the_post_thumbnail_url($post_id, 'large');

$message = '
      Hi '.$author->display_name.',<br/><br/>

      Your post, '.$post->post_title.' has just been published.<br/>

      View post: <a href="'.get_permalink( $post_id ).'">'.get_permalink( $post_id ).'</a><br/>

      Your Image: <img src="'.$image.'" /><br/><br/>

      Thanks';

   wp_mail($author->user_email, $subject, $message);
   remove_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type', 'set_html_content_type' );
}
add_action('publish_post', 'mysendmail');
```

Comment: Added some formatting for you and linked up the posts title too